# Related Lists are not working in Lightning page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, page-layout

I have two users with two different profiles such as System administrator and Full User assigned with same page layout , for System Administrator profile related list is showing the custom object, but for full user profile in related list custom object is not showing

if profile is facing with object permissions and field permissions it is showing in classic view properly, but i am facing this issue in lightning record page only?

> why in Lightning record page , in related list custom object is not
>   showing?

if anyone knows please help me for this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Salesforce Docs

> Description
>
> If a Custom Object Related List (via a lookup relationship to another
>   Object with a corresponding Related List) appears in Classic but not
>   Lightning, review the Field Level Security of the Object with the
>   missing Related List.
>
> Resolution
>
> To display the Related List in Lightning, the Custom Object's [Field
>   Level Security](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_fls.htm&type=0) must be set to "Visible" for all profiles (not set as
>   "Hidden").

So check for the field permission as well.

[Custom Object Related Lists missing in Lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249344&type=1)