# Cases related list on Product not showing up in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, case

I have Cases that are logged against Assets, and I see them under Products record page layout as well in Classic (see image below). It is standard system behavior, that the products record show cases related to Assets (standard relationship).

[image]

> **Problem**

All looks nice in Classic but in the **Lightning experience** it only shows Assets related list.

[image]

> What have I tried so far?

- I have looked at another question [Related Lists are not working in Lightning page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207429/related-lists-are-not-working-in-lightning-page)
- Salesforce [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249344&type=1) pertaining to similar problem
- Ensured that the Case related list is added to the concerned Product page layout
- Tried to add a "Related List - Single" component by editing the Product Lightning page editor but Cases don't appear in that option either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged a case with Salesforce and got the following response

> I would like to follow up with you regarding this case. From my
>   previous update, I informed you that I did additional testing in my
>   demo org and was able to add the case related list to the product page
>   layout in Classic, I then created a product record and associated it
>   to an asset. However, when logging a case against the asset, then
>   going back to the product record, nothing appeared in the case related
>   list.
>
> As for Lighting, the product case related list did not appear even
>   though it is added to the page layout in Classic. After further
>   investigating, I found a R&D investigation regarding this behavior.
>   Even though the case related list is added to the product page layout
>   in Classic, **R&D has no plans to bring this behavior to Lighting and is
>   prioritizing normal use cases for the Case Related List** as product is
>   not typically a parent for case (nor opportunity).